# Trouble submitting form information

Tags: next.js, material-ui

I had a question like this but has since been closed due to code being too long so I'll try to keep it briefer.

I have a form that my partner made but all the `<Select>` inputs gets sent through the HTTP request as "undefined", only the fields where typing is required are coming through properly and neither of us are sure why or how to fix it.

```
<form action="/api/cardAdd" method="post">
(Other parts of the form)
    <Box>
      <FormControl
       variant="standard"
       sx={{ width: "100%", paddingBottom: "5px" }}
       >
       <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-standard-label">
         Card Type
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
         labelId="demo-simple-select-standard-label"
         id="demo-simple-select-standard"
         value={cardType}
         onChange={handleCardTypeChange}
         label="Card Type"
         >
           <MenuItem value="">
           <em>None</em>
           </MenuItem>
             {types.map((type) => (
             <MenuItem key={type} value={type}>
               {type}
             </MenuItem>
              ))}
         </Select>
    </Box>
</form>
```

This is only one of the input fields but the rest are the same, except the names are different and the other 2 `Select` fields have the "multiple" attribute so we can select more than 1 option.

These are the states and onChange methods:

```
const [cardType, setCardType] = useState("");
const [cardSymbols, setCardSymbols] = useState([]);
const [cardKeywords, setCardKeywords] = useState([]);

const handleCardTypeChange = (event) => {
    setCardType(event.target.value);
  };

const handleSymbolChange = (event) => {
    const {
      target: { value },
    } = event;
    setCardSymbols(typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value);
  };

const handleKeywordChange = (event) => {
    const {
      target: { value },
    } = event;
    setCardKeywords(typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value);
  };
```

I tried placing using a seperate `<form>` where I attempted to pass the values to this separate form and tried swapping the "cardSymbols" and "symbols" names around because "symbols" is what its called in the API so I thought it was maybe a naming issue but that hasn't worked.

Attempts to use join() doesn't work, when I console.log(typeof cardSymbols) it comes back as an object so I tried using Object.entries() to try to change it into an array before being sent off by the form but it is still undefined when I console.log(symbols) in the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out it was a string, excuse the pun, of problems.

Firstly `<Select>` did not have the `name` attribute so it was not being passed to the backend.

Secondly even after adding the `name` attribute, it was being sent to the backend as a `string` therefore it needed to be converted to an `array` despite the fact that it was already an array in the frontend.

This also meant that `setCardKeywords(typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value);` needed to be changed to `setCardKeywords(value)` for all instances because it wasn't doing anything.